# Amazon S3 CURL command to COPY folder from one Container to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

I am new to S3, we need to move a Folder present in one container to  another using CURL command. Both the containers have access to single key.I am trying to write a sample code:

```
container=container_source // This is my Source container
resource="https://container_source.****.***.com/Folder1/"
contentType="application/octet-stream"
dateValue=`date -R`
stringToSign="COPY\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key=b12***********
s3Secret=7************************
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
nohup curl -X COPY -T "container_source.****.***.com/Folder1/" \
  -H "Host: ${container}.****.***.com" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
  https://container_dest.****.***.com/Folder1
```

Comment: Why not use aws cli? You can simply transfer it with ease. aws s3 mv s3://mybucket/Folder1 s3://mybucket1/Folder1 --recursive

Comment: aws cli is not installed on this machine.if I can get a command to transfer one file. I know the ways to do it in a recursive manner by pulling the metadata.